# Unknown provider: $scopeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created an application in AngularJS with having **[Skinny AngularJS Controllers](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers#disqus_thread)**. The application is working fine but the issue is that when I tried to access another controller through by using `$controller('ControllerOne')` I am getting the following exception.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqnrrL8y/)**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:78:12
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3451:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3578:39)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3456:45
    at getService (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3578:39)
    at invoke (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3600:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3636:23)
    at $get (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:6639:28)
    at new <anonymous> (http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:47:22)
    at invoke (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3624:28)
```

My code is as given below

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['firstApp', 'secondApp']);

var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
firstApp.controller('ControllerOne', function ($scope) {
    this.name = "Messi";
});

var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', []);
secondApp.controller('ControllerTwo', function ($scope, $controller) {
    $scope.ctrlOne = $controller('ControllerOne');
});
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: Why do you need to access controller one through controller two?

Comment: I need to access  some methods and variables in ControllerOne from ControllerTwo

Comment: If there is common variables or methods that should be available across both controller why not create a service that both modules can consume. You shouldn't make one controller's implementation depend on another's implementation.

Comment: It's worth noting using the below answers you will be able to create another instance of ControllerOne, but it will not be the same as sharing an already instantiated instance and therefore it won't be sharing any data already set in another instance of a Controller in your app. As @zeSimon correctly points out. You should be using services. Or put the data you want to share on the rootscope (this is also a bad idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is a very good idea to do it like you are doing, but here is a solution:

```
secondApp.controller('ControllerTwo', function ($scope, $controller) {
    $scope.ctrlOne = $controller('ControllerOne', {$scope: $scope});
});
```

The problem is that according to definition of `ControllerOne` it expects one dependency injection service: `$scope`. So you need to provide this service.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oqnrrL8y/2/

Answer (score 1):

`$controller` will instantiate the controller.

You need to pass the scope to it.

`ctrl1 = $controller('ControllerOne', {$scope: $scope})`

Here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/oqnrrL8y/1/